# How to include other modules from same directory while compiling an executable using pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am trying to turn a Tkinter program into executable file. My application consists of two .py scripts. 'gui.py' containing the gui frontend: widgets like buttons etc. 'functions.py' containing functions etc. invoked by widgets from 'gui.py'. 
I am compiling 'gui.py' using '--onefile' option in pyinstaller. The executable thus generated only renders widgets without functionality from 'funciton.py'.

I have tried using '--hidden-import' and '--additional-hooks' options to no avail.

PS: My code runs fine in Spyder IDE environment. No error messgae is dispalyed.